# Access two or more tokens in one line using Bison

Tags: parsing, token, bison, yacc, flex-lexer

I am using bison to implement a simple parser. And one line of the syntax looks like:

```
prefix_definition : PREFIX IDENTIFIER IDENTIFIER ABBR IDENTIFIER ';'
```

I am unsure how to access the 1st, 2nd and 3rd `IDENTIFIER` separately. My flex file reads the `IDENTIFIER` like this:

```
IDENTIFIER_REGEX (_|[A_Za-z])(_|[0-9A-Za-z])*

{IDENTIFIER_REGEX}     { yylval.identifier=strdup(yytext); return IDENTIFIER; }
```

I could not use simply `yylval.identifier`. I tried `$2.identifier` or so but it simply does not work(and it is not supposed to be work anyway). Is there any way of solving this problem?

I am considering to use a FIFO queue if the bison/flex does not support such access. Is this a good solution?

Comment: I removed the "Adobe Flex" tag and added the "gnu-flex" tag; as I think this post deals w/ the lexical analyzer; not the Flash Platform SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the type of a token while declaring it (in the bison file) the same way you would for nonterminals (where you'd use `%type`) like so:

```
%token <identifier> IDENTIFIER
```

(where `identifier` is one of the fields declared in the `%union`). Then `$2`, `$3` and so on will point to the right thing, without needing to go through `yylval` (i.e. they will be `char *`s in your case).

Comment: It works. Indeed I just confused $2 $3 etc. with yylval and thought they are contents.